# How to manipulate dict properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this dictionary:

```
self.rewards = {'D': -1,'0':100,'&':-100}
```

`'D'` is a key for a standard reward `-1`.

`'0'` is a key for a good reward `100`.

`'&'` is a key for a bad reward `-100`.

Now I need to change that reward system in a mode where the GOOD and BAD rewards are the key itself for example:

```
self.rewards = {'D': -1, key : key}

#Example:
    #next.tipo is 'D'
    self.rewards[next.tipo] #is -1
    #next.tipo is '10500'
    self.rewards[next.tipo] #is 10500
    #next.tipo is '-4500'
    self.rewards[next.tipo] #is -4500
```

That is possible?

Other way that I thought:

```
self.rewards = {'D': -1, else : key}
```

Reading above: If the key is `'D'` then the value is `-1`, ELSE the value is the key itself.

Comment: While everyone is happily hammering out proposals, I still have a question: What is the relation to the title and why should a dict be a good implementation for the concept. I think a function is more promising when only one key shall result in `-1` all others simply "echo the input values". Another hint: A set is a dict where the values are the keys ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get`-method of dicts:

```
reward = int(self.rewards.get(next.tipo, next.tipo))
```

Comment: can i do:/
next.tipo = '1050'/
test = int(self.rewards.get(next.tipo, next.tipo)) + 100/
print test/
>>>>1150

Comment: @Kondecigs: try it, and you will see, you can.

Answer (score 1):

Why not building a function:

```
def getRewards(val):
    return -1 if val=='D' else val

In [195]: getRewards(100)
Out[195]: 100

In [196]: getRewards('D')
Out[196]: -1
```

Comment: thanks, sad to see most of programmers over there are just 'realizing tasks' and not thinking ...

Comment: ... sometimes we do all just want to deliver to get **it** off of our list, don't we?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is possible.

```
>>> keys = ['hello','D']
>>> d = dict()
>>> for k in keys:
...     if k == 'D':
...             d[k] = -1
...     else:
...             d[k] = k
... 
>>> d
{'hello': 'hello', 'D': -1}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a dict comprehension:

```
 self.rewards = {k: k for k, v in self.rewards.items()}
 self.rewards['D'] = -1
```

Comment: If my key is '10500' the value will be '10500' and i need to do cast to float, where i do that cast?

Comment: hum, you won't be able to do this with a dict comprehension, you should use a loop on dict items.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following

```
t ={v: v for k, v in self.rewards.items() if k is not 'D'}
t['D'] = self.rewards.get('D')
```